# How to total sum using jquery in td class?

Tags: jquery

I have been wondering if what is the best way to change the total sum in my table using jquery im using this

```
 var Beginbal = 0;
$(".beginbal").change(function () {
    $(".beginbal").each(function () {
        if ($(this).html() != "") {
            Beginbal += parseFloat($(this).html());
        }
        console.log(Beginbal);
    });
    $(".NoOfBeginBal").html(Beginbal);
});
```

Comment: I think you're doing fine.

Comment: A `change` event is on `input`, and `.html()` for input? Try with `.val()`

Comment: but it doesnt change the given output it doesnt calculate it,,,Shaunak D on input should change the values

Comment: i tried .val() but no values shown even i tried .html no output

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Beginbal += parseFloat($(this).html()) || 0;
```